# How does stackoverflow implement the continual page updates?

Tags: javascript, ajax

It's stunning - you open stackoveflow question and the page is modifying itself in front of your eyes!

*"Ah, that's obvious",* I thought. They just keep sending AJAX requests to the server to check if something changed.

**Nope!** I opened Firebug plugin for Firefox and looked at the Net panel. There were no AJAX requests sent during several minutes. And as you may have experienced, the page is updated much more often than once per minute!

Do you have an idea how is this implemented?

Comment: PS: as this is technical programmer question I don't feel it belongs to meta and prefer to ask it here.

Comment: The magic word is [WebSocket](https://www.google.de/#hl=de&q=Websockets)!

Comment: See also http://signalr.net/

Comment: To closer: your close reason doesn't apply: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."* I'am not asking for code in the first place.

Comment: @Tomas I haven't voted to close, but this question seems like it would be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's a technical question about how a technical feature was implemented. I think it's ok here...

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus thank you! Didn't know this technology!

Comment: Check these links
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148533/what-is-sockets-ny-stackexchange-com and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure but I'd expect it is using WebSocket in HTML 5 and Long Polling before then. Those are the usual approaches for this sort of live update functionality.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Answer (score 4):

Usually someone coming from Node.js uses socket.io for something like this. However SO uses C# / ASP.NET MVC
so their equivalence of socketio would be **[SocketIO4Net](http://socketio4net.codeplex.com).**

Comment: Nope, they use C# / ASP.NET MVC / SQL Server - see their Careers 2.0 page http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/34229/full-stack-web-developer-stack-exchange

Comment: The idea is pretty much the same. Check out this link http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/

Comment: You're completely right, but your answer is somewhat misleading. I just didn't want users coming to this page to think that SO uses node.js.